# What type of email should I use for nodemailer to not get blocked

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

I tried to figure out the problem, but everything was correctly configured. I'm used gmail, but when I deployed my nodejs website, immediately been blocked. After I tried outlook email, a had a few problems to set up, but worked on localhost, and worked on server too. After a day, when I wanted to try, it was blocked too. What type of email should I use, which is free, and working perfectly with nodemailer and not blocking, when someone want to send email when the website is on a server?

```js
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
      secureConnection: false,
      port: 587,
      tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
      },
      auth: {
        user: 'example@outlook.com',
        pass: 'xxxx'
      }
    });

  let mailOptions = {
    from: '<example@outlook.com>',
    to: 'example@outlook.com',
    subject: 'Beküldött recept: ' + req.body.recipename,
    text: '',
    html: "",
    attachments: [{
      filename: imageName,
      path: newuploadPath
    }]
  };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used [Zoho mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/) and it works fine. Make sure to use the same Zoho email address in the `from` field of `mailOptions` as it will throw an error otherwise.

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.zoho.eu',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, //ssl
    auth: {
        user:process.env.EMAIL,
        pass:process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL,
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: "Subject",
    html: ""
};
```

Generally Gmail is not the preferred service to use with Nodemailer since it is targeted at real users and not for automatic/programmed use. See [Nodemailer with Gmail](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/) for more info. Also here is a list of alternative email services supported by Nodemailer [WELL-KNOWN SERVICES](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/well-known-services/).

Comment: Thank you, i will try zoho mail, for 0,90€ per month is a good offer.

Comment: Glad to help,  I set up Zoho email for free when I used it for my hobby project. So make sure to see all available options they offer. Maybe the free one will work for you.

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me, for free. Thank you!